# Link {{store url}} not linking to the right spot

Tags: cms, magento-1.6, static-block

I'm using {{store url}} linking in some static pages to link to other product pages. But when I'm linking to .html pages, they end up with a / after, so .html/ and that dosen't work correctly.

I want to link to some pre-selected layered navigation with this:

```
... onclick="location.href='{{store url='www.site.com/category1/category2/product.html?attribute=1383'}}'"
```

This gives the url http:.//www.site.com/category1/category2/product.html?attribute=1383/ <- and because of the / my sorting is not showing up. Is the / normal, or am I doing something the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to generate the url is:

```
{{store _direct="category1/category2/product.html" _query="attribute=1383"}}
```